# Implements sum of powers of q multiplicated for list elements recursively

Tags: java, list, recursion, nodes, abstract-class

I need to write a program which allows to calculate the sums of powers of a number **q** starting from exponent **i = 0** multiplicated for the **i** element of a list of node

The method must have this signature

`public double eval (double q)`

And it is an abstract method of the abstract class **List**

```
abstract class List{ 
      abstract double eval(double q);
}
```

implemented by

```
class Nil extends List{

       public double eval(double q){

           //Method to implement
        }
}


class Cons extends List{

     int elem;
     List next;

     public Cons(int elem, List next){

          this.elem = elem;
          this.next = next;
     }

      public double eval(double q){

        //Method to implements

       }
}
```

I tried to implement by myself
Here it is my try for **Cons**:

```
public double eval(double q){

  return elem * q + next.eval(q*q);

 }
```

Whereas for **Nil**:

```
public double eval(double q){

  return 0;
}
```

In this way i can calculate the powers of **q^i** for the element of the list at index **i**, but i can't add to the return value the results of First element for **q^0**. How can implement this behaviour without adding any other parameters besides of **q**?

**I need to implement this without using methods of the Java standard class**

**Example**

```
Input: inputList = [1,2,3]
method: inputList.eval(5) 
output: 1 * 5^0 + 2 * 5^1 + 3 * 5^2 = 1 + 10 +  75 = 86
```

**Code Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
      Cons list = new Cons(1,new Cons(2, new Cons(3, new Nil());

       System.out.println(list.eval(5));
       //It should output 1 * 5^0 + 2 * 5^1 + 3 * 5^2 = 1 + 10 +  75 = 86 but in the way i implemented It i can't calculate the First element of the list * 5^0

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to calculate `list.get(0)*q^0 + list.get(1)*q^1 + list.get(2) q^2 .......+ list.get(n)*q^n` ?

Comment: @c0der yes, i want to calculate it recursively

Comment: Please add a test case (hard coded data) and expected result.

Comment: I've added an example of the requested behaviour

Comment: `List` has only one method so it is not a container . Is something missing  ?

Comment: nothing missed, the list class Is extended in **Cons** and **Nil** classes which represent the nodes of the list.

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Comment: I think you got an answer to the question asked. Please post new information in a new post.